# how to uppercase only first in zend form inputs?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, ucfirst

I am working with Zend Form, and on the edit i want the values to be like  `ucfirst(values) ;`.
I found filters   `'filters' => array('StringToUpper')` but they work on the hole input. 
Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such filter exists but it would be trivial to create your own:

```
 class My_Filter_StringUCFirst implements Zend_Filter_Interface {
     public function filter($value){
         return ucfirst($value);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's time for a [custom filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.filter.writing_filters.html).

Something like:

```
class UcFirstFilter implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
    public function filter($value)
    {
        // perform some transformation upon $value to arrive on $valueFiltered
        $valueFiltered=ucfirst($value);
        return $valueFiltered;
    }
}
$filterChain = new Zend_Filter();
$filterChain->addFilter(new UcFirstFilter());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution , i've changed my populate function :

```
public function populate($data) {
 ....

    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {

            if (in_array($field, array("fields you want in ucfirst")) )
                $value=  ucfirst ($value);

            $this->{$field}->setValue($value);
      }

    return $this;
}
```

Hope this will help.